# Android Back Button Event Mapping with Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Is there any way to map the default back button event in android to sencha touch without using phonegap/cordova???

Comment: What exactly do you want the back button to do? If you want to move between views then you should utilize hash routes. These will work even when the app is not bundled natively.

Comment: i have hash routes...yes that works but i want the back button to basically go back screens like window.history.back() like in any browser. Instead right now it just exits the app which is not what i want... What i am asking is, is there a way to map window.history.back() to android's back button using sencha???

Answer (score 1):

May be this, helpful:

```
    if (Ext.os.is('Android')) {
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", Ext.bind(onBackKeyDown, this), false);  // add back button listener
      function onBackKeyDown(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          // You are at the home screen
          if (Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().xtype == selectedHomePage.xtype ){
                Ext.Msg.confirm(
                    "",
                    Are You sure, exit?,
                    function(buttonId) {
                        if(buttonId === 'yes') {
                            navigator.app.exitApp();
                        }
                }, this);
          } else {
          }
      }
   }
```